# Adding a new channel to an image

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, computer-vision

I am trying to add a 4th "channel" to an image. Specifically, I have a RGB image and would like append that image matrix with an edge detection layer as found by a Canny filter, which I will then use as an input for a neural network.

I have edge detection working, and I can even append the images, but for some reason, the data 'reverts' after looping. The changes that I make in the size of the image do not stick.

---

**Code**

I have three sets of `32x32x3` color images: `X_train`, `X_valid`, and `X_test`. For each one, I am normalizing the image and then appending the gradient. Appending appears to take affect while looping, but the changes do not exist after looping.

*Code snippet*

```
import cv2 as cv
example_record = 2

print('X_train is shape {}'.format(X_train.shape))
print('X_valid is shape {}'.format(X_valid.shape))
print('X_test is shape {}'.format(X_test.shape))

# Show before
plt.imshow(X_valid[example_record])
plt.title('Validation Input {} Before Normalization'.format(example_record))

# Normalize
canny_low = 50
canny_high = 100
for dataset in [X_train, X_valid, X_test]:
    for i, img in enumerate(dataset):
        cv.normalize(img, img, 0, 255, cv.NORM_MINMAX)
        edges = cv.Canny(img, canny_low, canny_high)
        edges = np.reshape(edges, (img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 1))
        img = np.concatenate((img, edges),axis=2)
        if i == 0:
            print('img shape after concatenation {}'.format(img.shape))

# Show after
plt.figure()
print('Updated image shape: {}'.format(X_valid[example_record].shape))
plt.imshow(X_valid[example_record])
plt.title('Validation Input {} After Normalization'.format(example_record))
```

*Output*

```
X_train is shape (34799, 32, 32, 3)
X_valid is shape (4410, 32, 32, 3)
X_test is shape (12630, 32, 32, 3)
img shape after concatenation (32, 32, 4)
img shape after concatenation (32, 32, 4)
img shape after concatenation (32, 32, 4)
Updated image shape: (32, 32, 3)
```

---

**Other Attempts**

If I replace `img = np.concatenate((img, edges),axis=2)` with `dataset[i] = np.concatenate((img, edges),axis=2)`, I get the error:

```
     21         edges = cv.Canny(img, canny_low, canny_high)
     22         edges = np.reshape(edges, (img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 1))
---> 23         dataset[i] = np.concatenate((img, edges),axis=2)
     24         if i == 0:
     25             print('img shape after concatenation {}'.format(img.shape))

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (32,32,4) into shape (32,32,3)
```

Comment: I highly recommend writing img to a new list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, my previous answer was not detailed enough for someone's taste and it was down-voted. So, let me provide a "ready" solution:

```
# Normalize
canny_low = 50
canny_high = 100
X = [X_train, X_valid, X_test]
X_new = [np.empty(x.shape[:-1] + (x.shape[-1] + 1,), dtype=x.dtype) for x in X]

for dataset, dsnew in zip(X, X_new):
    for i, img in enumerate(dataset):
        cv.normalize(img, img, 0, 255, cv.NORM_MINMAX)
        edges = np.expand_dims(cv.Canny(img, canny_low, canny_high), axis=2)
        dsnew[i, :, :, :] = np.concatenate((img, edges), axis=2)
```

Alternatively, you could expand `X_train`, `X_valid`, and `X_test` *before* the loop starts and this may save some memory.

Comment: Yes! I tried both this approach and by expanding the datasets themselves, and both worked well. I was stuck thinking that `img` was a reference rather than a copy.

Answer (score 0):

1. You inner loop

   ```
   for i, img in enumerate(dataset):
   ```

   is overwriting the value of concatenated `img`
2. Your

   ```
   print('X_train is shape {}'.format(X_train.shape))
   print('X_valid is shape {}'.format(X_train.shape))
   print('X_test is shape {}'.format(X_train.shape))
   ```

   is printing the value of the shape of `X_train.shape`!
3. After the line

   img = np.concatenate(...)

   inside the loop, what do you do with the concatenated image `img`? Don't you think you have to store the result somehow for the program to "remember" it?

Your second attempt is promising, just do not store new `img` in the `dataset`. Define a `dataset_new` outside the loop (make an empty list or numpy array of the correct shape) and then in the loop do `dataset_new[i] = np.concatenate...`.

Comment: This answer does touch upon the issue but not the solution. You should add something more.